# Date/Time formatting issue while webscraping to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I'm learning python and software development...

I've been scraping data (date/time, interest rate) every minute since July from a website and appending it to a CSV file. Today I went to chart the data using jupyter notebook, pandas..etc

I sliced off the 'AM/PM' string characters and used the `pandas.to_datetime` method on the date/time column to properly format it and .

```
data['date/time'] = data['date/time'].str[0:14].map(pandas.to_datetime)
```

However, it appears that the date/time data was at first interpreted by python/jupyter/pandas following the ddmmyy convention but then changed at the start of a new month to being interpreted to mmddyy. On the 13th of the month the interpretation changed back to ddmmyy.

For example:

The CSV file shows the following string value within the respective cell:

```
31/07/22 23:59PM
01/08/22 00:00AM
...
12/08/22 23:59PM
13/08/22 00:00AM
```

However, the pandas dataframe, after using the 'to_datetime' method shows:

```
2022-07-31 23:59:00
2022-01-08 00:00:00
...
2022-12-08 23:59:00
2022-08-13 00:00:00
```

I've been trying to figure out:
Why this happened?
How can I avoid this moving forward?
How can I fix this so that I may chart/plot the time series data properly?

***Update***It looks like the issue occurs while filtering from a larger CSV file into the CSV file I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `pandas.to_datetime` dayfirst parameter set to `True` to assume the format as `day/month/year`. Otherwise, it assumes the format is `month/day/year` if `1 <= month <= 12`.

It's going to be like the following:

```py
data['date/time'] = data['date/time'].str[0:14].map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst=True))
```

Comment: Perfect - it's always a simple fix. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to know that! Also, I'd be grateful (and other users too) if you accept the answer ✅ as the right one.